# TradingView price change percentage calculation

Tags: pine-script

I wonder how the price increase/decrease in being calculated on TradingView? We have open and close price but the price difference (left arrow) seems not to be correct neither is percentage (right arrow)

```
difference = open - close
```

which results in -0.0009 but TradingView calculates -0.0005

Also percentage seems to be different:

```
difference = ((open - close) / open) * 100
```

Which results in **-0.39%** but TradingView shows **-0.22%**

How TradingView is calculating the price difference?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is **change**. You should compare the previous `close` with the current `price`.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

price_change = close - close[1]
per_change = (close-close[1]) / close[1] * 100

plot(price_change, color=color.blue)
plot(per_change, color=color.white)
plot(close - open, color=color.red)     // This is how you do it which is not how Tradingview calculates it
```

[image]

Comment: that makes absolutely sense! I was assuming that previous candle close price is/should be the same as current candle open price, which is definitely not the case! Thank you for pointing that out